# Static variables is reset to null after a while

Tags: c#, list, constructor, static

I have a `static member` which is a list and it appears that it sometimes gets reset to `null` for some reason (maybe after an uncaught exception).
Here is my code:

```
public abstract partial class MyClass
{
            private static List<MyClass> Types;

            static MyClass()
            {
                Types = new List<MyClass>();
                Types.Add(new Myclass(0));
                Types.Add(new Myclass(1));
            }


            public static MyClass GetMyClass(int id)
            {                
                return Types.Single(x => x.id == id);
            }
}
```

The `GetMyClass` method will then fire a `null` reference exception.
Nowhere in my code do I set this member to `null`.
Do you have an idea?

Here is the complete code if that can help:

```
public partial class TestRequest
{
    public abstract partial class TrType
    {
        private static List<TrType> Types;

        static TrType()
        {
            Types = new List<TrType>();
            Types.Add(TrType.Real.Instance);
            Types.Add(TrType.Template.Instance);
        }
        protected int idTrType;

        public static TrType GetTrType(int id)
        {
            return Types.Single(x => x.idTrType == id);
        }

        public int IdTrType
        {
            get { return idTrType; }
            set { idTrType = value; }
        }

        public abstract void Launch(TestRequest tr);
    }
}

// In another file.

public partial class TestRequest
{
    public partial class TrType
    {
        public class Real : TestRequest.TrType
        {
            private static Real instance;
            public const int ID = 1;

            protected Real()
            {
                idTrType = ID;
            }

            static Real()
            {
                instance = new Real();
            }

            public static Real Instance
            {
                get { return instance; }
                set { instance = value; }
            }

            public override void Launch(TestRequest tr)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever add a `null` element to `Types`? That's the only way I can see it happening.

Comment: No, the only place I insert elements is in this static constructor.

Comment: Ok, then how is the `id` property's `get` implemented? That's the last place I can see here that could possibly throw an NRE (assuming that's what's actually being thrown).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are getting an exception because of [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). *(Its not NRE)*

> The Single(IEnumerable) method throws an exception
>   if the input sequence is empty. To instead return null when the input
>   sequence is empty, use SingleOrDefault.

Try:

```
 return Types.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
```

That will return null if none is found. But you will still get an exception if more than one item is found against the `id`

Comment: The exception occurs when Types is null, not when I give an incorrect id in the parameter.

Comment: @user3099700, and you are sure you are not clearing the list anywhere ?

Comment: @user3099700, just instantiate it at the time of declaration, instead of static constructor, `private static List<MyClass> Types = new List<MyClass>();` I am not sure if this would have any effect, but just give it a shot

Comment: Clever, but this answer does not address the NRE.  The OP explicitly stated he is receiving a NRE.  According to MSDN, that type of exception is not thrown by Single.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why it would be reset to null.  How about setting it to readonly so it can only be set in the static constructor and never be changed.  However, the list can be modified later.

```
    public abstract partial class MyClass
    {
        private static readonly List Types;

        static MyClass()
        {
            Types = new List<MyClass>();
            Types.Add(new Myclass(0));
            Types.Add(new Myclass(1));
        }


        public static MyClass GetMyClass(int id)
        {
            return Types.Single(x => x.id == id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, readonly should then produce a compile time error where the list is being reassigned. It won't however prevent e.g. all the elements from being removed.

Comment: @StuartLC - An empty argument will not throw an NRE.  This is a good answer +1.

Comment: I'll keep this solution in mind, but I doubt it won't change anything. I have triple checked, I never assign this list anywhere else.

Comment: If you're concerned about the list changing later, you could switch to a readonly collection.
private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<T> Types;

Then at the end of the static constructor: Types = list.AsReadOnly()

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably lies with code you have not displayed to us.  NRE on this static private variable can be solved by making the variable readonly.

Looking carefully there's a few problems:

1. This is a partial class.  In all likelihood that means something has been left out of the example and is causing the problem.  The accessibility is private so the variable can only be set to null by the containing class.  There's nothing shown in the OP that will cause the variable to "reset to null".  However, marking the variable read only (make the class immutable) will solve run time errors of this type and avoid side effects caused by other members of the class.
2. There's a casing problem with `Types.Add(new`**Myclass**`(0));`.  I assume this is just a type-o and not a design issue (e.g. inheritance) that has not been explained.
3. We do not have a definition for `x.id`.  It might be a new class it might be an extension of the partial (we need the answer to #2 to be sure).  IF `x.id` is nullable and `x` is null then that will cause an NRE.  *Note that if `Types` is empty you will  NOT receive an NRE, you will if `Types` is null*

Comment: Indeed, I haven't put all my code, but the other parts are irrelevant. The casing problem is also a typo, as my real class is actually not "MyClass" :)

Comment: @user3099700 - Even so, the options of what can be wrong are limited given the accessibility of the variable.  As explained in 1st point and 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally could reproduce the problem.
I have been wrong since the beginning. The NRE was caused in the Linq expression :

```
Types.Single(x => x.id == id);
```

The 'x' would be null (not Types as I thought) and this can happen when I access the "Real" instance first (before TrType initialization). In that case, the static constructor of "Real" is called in order to instanciate the "instance" property. Since "Real" inherits from "TrType", the static constructor of "TrType" is called, and the "Types" list construction begins. It then tries to insert the instance of "Real" which is still in the process of being instanciated and thus is still null at that time. We then have a "null" object in the list...

Thanks all for your participations.